# jQuery event with Alert "OK" button clicked

Tags: jquery, local-storage, alert

I have a `jQuery` function that triggers an alert pop-up when clicked. I need a another event to trigger when that OK button is hit. In this case the user is agreeing to something, I need to store a variable to localstorage that they agreed. My current code for alert:

```
$('.external').click( function() { alert("You are now leaving site"); });
```

Comment: Use a `confirm` box: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm

Comment: I suggest you should create a modal for the first alert and then on OK click , show the window alert.

Comment: as for the localstorage part of the question, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)  out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for `confirm()`. Try this:

```
$('.external').click(function (e) {
    var r = confirm("You are now leaving site");
    if (r == true) {
        // user agreed, do something 
    } else {
        // user did not agree, do something else
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**EDIT 1:**

As per @JohnCarpenter, regarding `localStorage`: [Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)

**EDIT 2:**

To redirect the page upon confirmation, use something like this:

```
window.location.replace("http://domain.com");
```

You could also get fancy with jQuery and get the URL dynamically from the original anchor's `href` attribute:

```
window.location.replace($(this).prop('href'));
```

Please also see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-using-jquery) regarding `window.location.replace`. It's possible that `window.location.href` would better suit your needs.

Comment: good answer, for the localstorage part of the question, [this stack overflow link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage) is a good one.

Comment: @Stuart Good answer. When using confirm() what is the correct way to not follow the link if user selects cancel?

Comment: @Sam Adding `e.preventDefault();` while passing the closure within the `click` call an event object (`e`) will prevent the browser's default behavior of navigating to the link. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @Staurt e.preventDefault(); stops the link, how would allow it if r== true?